# Unknown error when opening VBA module in Developer Window

Tags: excel, vba

My `xlsm` file has been crashing in every instance, including in Excel's Safe Mode.

Upon hitting ESC repeatedly, I was able to view the spreadsheet, but upon opening the Developer window and double-clicking on a module - I see the error below, though, with no message.

[image]

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Restarting computer, clearing cache, copying file